# Why do my normal sync codelines, works like async?

Tags: javascript

I made this createElement function, which is works because it's extends the dom, but why the alert and below the console.log says: 'undefined'?
Feels like async the execution.

```js
const trial = createElement(body[0], 'h2', 'delay or not delay', null, null);
alert(trial);
console.log(trial, 'trial');
```

And the createElement function:

```js
function createElement(parent, tagname, textcontent, id, clas) {
    let element = document.createElement(tagname);
    if (textcontent) {
        element.textContent = textcontent;
    }
    if (id) {
        element.setAttribute('id', id);
    }
    if (clas) {
        element.setAttribute('class', clas)
    }
    parent.appendChild(element)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `createElement` function returns nothing.